# How to use a SSD partition as a cache for 2tb HDD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd

I have a Seagate Barracuda 2TB HDD and an SK 500GB Hynix Gold S31 SSD. I'm using the SSD as a boot drive and the HDD as a game library. Is there a way to make a partition of the SSD and use it as a cache for my 2TB game drive? or is Optane the only way?

Comment: Google is a life saver here... https://www.wepc.com/tips/ssd-cache/

Comment: This is all great and fine and you are right.. it ***will*** speed everything up nicely.. but don't forget that using the SSD as a game cache is certain to ***SERIOUSLY shorten*** the lifespan of that drive.. [in some cases.. down to mere months](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk03wtfHlfN9s_FPKS7afqV34HSAPGQ%3A1603414731491&ei=yyqSX4q_HdXY-wT6nL7QBQ&q=ssd+cache+estimated+lifespan&oq=ssd+cache+estimated+lifespan&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIGCAAQBxAeOgQIABBHUITUA1iT2gNgx9wDaABwAngAgAFKiAF-kgEBMpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQLAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjK0P2rwcnsAhVV7J4KHXqOD1oQ4dUDCAw&uact=5).